# how can i use webview object in cocoa to display webpage?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webview

i want to display the web page in my program ,i use the WebView object in my IB (.xib) but it dosent work ,is there any sampel code ,not doc or article?

view_w.h

```
     @interface view_w : NSObject {
    IBOutlet WebView* Web;
       }
   -(IBAction) google:(id) sender;
    @end
```

view_w.m

```
  -(IBAction) google:(id) sender


  {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
       [Web loadrequest:request];

    }
```

// error No -loadrequest: method found

Comment: You should specifically state how your web view didn't work.

Comment: Are we talking Max OS X or iOS here?

Answer (score 2):

You should connect the webview to an outlet of you view controller class. Then

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yoursite.com/"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [yourwebviewoutlet loadRequest:request];
```

That is all.

**edit** to suppress the warning about the method not found, specify the type correctly:

```
IBOutlet UIWebView * web; // and use lowercase for variables while you're at it.
```

Comment: thanks but i did write it, i had error ->  NO -Loadrequest: method found!

Comment: That's because you made it type `id`, so the compiler doesn't know which methods exist on the object (the compiler doesn't look at the word "Web", it looks at that line that says `id web`). see my updated answer.

Comment: when i use UIWebview //error expected specifire -qualifire -list before UIWebview
(i'm beginner in objective c & cocoa so i don't know about UI:D)

Comment: ok. this is programming. in programming you have to be precise. it looks like you didn't use an uppercase V for UIWeb **V** iew.

Comment: aden: Case matters in C and Objective-C. UIWebview is something totally different from UIWebView; most importantly, UIWebView exists whereas UIWebview doesn't (unless you made one, for some reason). Also, are you programming Cocoa, or Cocoa Touch? Cocoa has WebView, whereas Cocoa Touch has (as part of UIKit) UIWebView.

Comment: my programming is cocoa and UIWebView doesn't exist.
i also check IBOutlet WebView* web; i have errors too.

Answer (score 1):

// view.h

```
    #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
    #import<WebKit/WebKit.h>

     @interface view : NSObject {
   IBOutlet WebView* webview;
      }
     -(IBAction) google:(id) sender;

     @end
```

//view.m

```
   #import "view.h"

    @implementation view
      -(IBAction) google:(id) sender
      {
       [[webview mainFrame] loadRequest:
       [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
       [NSURL   URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/finance/converter"]]];
       }

      @end
```

Comment: Just dumping a lot of code doesn't illustrate exactly what the solution was. Again, please be *specific*.